# Read data from Google Storage Bucket to Array

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

How can I replace this function if I want to read the data from a Google Cloud Storage bucket (as opposed to local storage) and put it in an array like in this function?

```
def load_data(img_dir):
  return np.array(
    [cv2.imread(os.path.join(img_dir, img), 0).flatten() for img in os.listdir(img_dir) if img.endswith(".jpg")])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use OpenCV's [`imdecode`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4.13.7/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imdecode#cv2.imdecode) function instead, along with the [`google-cloud-storage`](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-storage/) package:

```
from google.cloud import storage

import numpy as np
import cv2

def load_data(bucket_name):
    bucket = storage.Client().get_bucket(bucket_name)

    return np.array(
        cv2.imdecode(
            np.asarray(bytearray(blob.download_as_string()), dtype=np.uint8), 0
        ).flatten()
        for blob in bucket.list_blobs()
        if blob.name.endswith(".jpg")
    )
```